# Tool or library for Graph Generation with export

Tags: library, java, c++, python, graphs

I'm about to start an academic project and I need to create **syntetic networks**, that is graphs with special properties.

The kinds of graphs (network **topologies**) I need to generate are:

- Erdos-Renyi
- Barabasi-Albert
- Random regular
- Watts-Strogatz (optional)

I may take 2 of the graphs generated using the above models and link them together, for example connecting an Erdos-Renyi graph with a Random regular graph.

I need a tool or a library capable of **generating** and **exporting** graphs. Acceptable export formats are: CSV, JSON, XML and gml files. The simpler the export format, the better.

Arcs in the graph can be **directed** or undirected, **weighted** or unweighted, and nodes should be able to contain basic information (e.g. a "consumption" parameter). The latter may be done through inheritance and is not crucial.

I do **not** need to **visualize** the generated graphs right now, I could use another tool for that. It would be nice to have, but what I care the most for is the quality of generated network.

My preference is for tools with a good documentation and **quality tutorials**.

I know **Java** and **C++**, with a preference for the former. I could use **Python** as well (if that's the best option), but I'm not really familiar with it.

Some of the libraries I'm considering are:

*JGraphT* is a famous Java library, has a comprehensive [JavaDoc](http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/), but its [tutorials](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki) are quite poor and it does not seem to be able to generate all the network topologies I need.

*Boost Graph Library* is a famous C++ library, has a comprehensive [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html), but I can't find any tutorials for it and I'm not sure it has all the generators I need.

*Neo4j* is a set of Java [algorithms](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-algorithms), has a comprehensive [JavaDoc](http://graphaware.com/site/algorithms/latest/apidocs/) but does not have tutorials and seems to miss the random regular [generator](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-algorithms#java).

*NetworkX* is a Python library that seems to have the best [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/index.html) and tutorials, it seems to have all the [generators](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.random_graphs) I need, but would require me to use Python. Is it really that good?

Your advise is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I would serious suggest taking a couple of days to make a start at learning python - it and its libraries are awesome both in simplicity of use and in power.  One of the big advantages of working in python is it works just about everywhere and you can even have a USB stick installation that will work without installation on most Windows machines - keep an backup of your work and tools on this and you can demo/make changes anywhere.

NetworkX is very good but I would also suggest taking a look at plotly/matplotlib/scipy for some additional tools.

To answer the last bit Python really is **that** good - there are just a couple of really important things to remember `<space>*n` is not equal to `<tab>` and if your code is not well laid out it will not run as you expect or not at all.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Unfortunately, I don't have time to learn Python properly. The library tutorials make it look like it's as simple as typing in a command line. Maybe I can manage it.